# Environment variable ORACLE_UNQNAME not defined. Please set ORACLE_UNQNAME to database unique name

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables, oracle-11g

I have a batch file which starts the Oracle Services

```
net start OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener
net start OracleServiceORCL
call C:\app\Edifixio\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN\emctl.bat start dbconsole
pause
```

But on executing the script I am getting:

```
C:\windows\system32>net start OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener
The requested service has already been started.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2182.


C:\windows\system32>net start OracleServiceORCL
The OracleServiceORCL service is starting.........
The OracleServiceORCL service was started successfully.


C:\windows\system32>call C:\app\Edifixio\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN\emctl.bat start dbconsole
Environment variable ORACLE_UNQNAME not defined. Please set ORACLE_UNQNAME to database unique name.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I am using Windows 7 64 bit with Oracle 11gR2 64 bit. Any information will be very helpful.
Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with, setting the variable, or picking the name?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams I found that I have to set `ORACLE_UNQNAME` to some value before invocation of the line `call C:\app\Edifixio\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN\emctl.bat start dbconsole`. But what is the value which is to be set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having installed Oracle about 20 times today, basically until I got it *all* working, and having experienced this problem, here are the two tips that really helped:

1. If you have multiple IP addresses, ensure the static address adapter is the primary, or add a Microsoft Loopback adapter with a 10.10.10.10 address per the Oracle pre-installation instructions.
   [Oracle Pre-installation Reqs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b14316/reqs.htm#BABGCEAI)
2. Add ORACLE_HOSTNAME and a value of [computer name] to your environment variables. This was the final step that finally fixed my em install.
   Note you need to check that you can resolve your machine to that address by both the qualified and unqualified machine name. You may need to tweak HOSTS to do this. 
   [Installing on Computers with Multiple IP Addresses](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b14316/reqs.htm#BABHFIBJ)

If these two things are correct, your listener.ora and tnsnames.ora will correctly match the separate em configuration, and you should avoid the requirement to set ORACLE_UNQNAME.

Best Wishes!

Answer (score 2):

From [Starting the Oracle Enterprise Manager Console](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10742/em_manage.htm):

> To access the Oracle Enterprise Manager Console from a client browser,
>   the dbconsole process needs to be running on the server. This process
>   is automatically started after installation.
>
> However, if the process is not running because of a system restart or
>   other event, you can manually start it at the command line.
>
> To start the dbconsole process:
>
> - Navigate into your `$ORACLE_HOME/bin directory`
> - Run the following statement:
>
>   ```
>   ./emctl start dbconsole
>   ```
>
> Additionally, you can stop the process and view its status.
>
> To stop the dbconsole process:
>
> ```
> ./emctl stop dbconsole
> ```
>
> To view the status of the dbconsole process:
>
> ```
> ./emctl status dbconsole
> ```

Now you put the URL into your browser. If you get a "page can't be
displayed" error, then you go to set your `ORACLE_HOME` and `ORACLE_SID`. And check your database is up and running.

Comment: Please always quote parts you did not write yourself, and properly attribute the original source. Anything else will be considered plagiarism and is strictly not allowed here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your global SID [1]. Your SID seems to be ORCL. from below line.

```
OracleServiceORCL
```

try using

```
SET ORACLE_UNQNAME=ORCL
```

if it fails

```
SET ORACLE_UNQNAME=ORCL.yourdomain.com
```

According to [2]
"I suspect ... that this was added to handle the situation where the SID and the unique name are different."

You can find db name and db_unique name with following SQL

```
Select name,DB_UNIQUE_NAME from v$database;
```

**References :**

[1] https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1035888
Last answer of 892845

[2] http://www.appsdba.com/blog/?p=305 :

Comment: Thanks for reply. I name and DB_UNIQUE_NAME is ORCL and orcl respectively. I have added `SET ORACLE_UNQNAME=ORCL` before `call C:\app\Edifixio\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN\emctl.bat start dbconsole` but I am getting `OC4J Configuration issue. C:\app\Edifixio\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1/oc4j/j2ee/OC4J_DBConsole_EDFX-LAPTOP-16_orcl not found.`

Comment: can you give contents of C:\app\Edifixio\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1/oc4j/j2ee/ directory

Comment: 1. home, 2. oc4j_applications, 3. OC4J_DBConsole, 4. OC4J_DBConsole_localhost_orcl, 5. OC4J_Workflow_Component_Container, 6. OC4J_Workflow_Management_Container, 7. utilities, all of these are folder and 8. deploy_db_wf is a file. This the content.

Comment: try to copy OC4J_DBConsole_localhost_orcl --> OC4J_DBConsole_EDFX-LAPTOP-16_orcl. Normally you should have a directory OC4J_DBConsole_MACHINE_NAME_SID there. Do your oracle machine have static IP?

Comment: EDFX-LAPTOP-16 is the hostname of the machine. Yes its static ip. Actually the public ip is static but the private one is dynamic.

Comment: Oracle does not like dynamic IP. I think your configuration changed from installation time to now.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to `$ORACLE_HOME/bin` and run:

```
emca -config dbcontrol db -repos recreate
```